# Jest Nestjs supertest cannot find module

Tags: nestjs, ts-jest, supertest

I am facing with the next error during my test run

```js
Error: Jest: Got error running globalSetup - 
reason: Cannot find module src/service
```

I have the next structure:
-src
-qa
In qa folder, there is a config file

```js
import { InitialOptions } from '@jest/types/build/Config';
const config: InitialOptions = {
  verbose: true,
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'json', 'ts'],
  rootDir: '../',
  globalSetup: './qa/global-setup.ts',
  globalTeardown: './qa/global-teardown.ts',
  testRunner: 'jest-jasmine2',
  testRegex: '.*-spec.ts$',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.ts$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['jest-allure/dist/setup'],
  testTimeout: 40 * 1000,
  moduleNameMapper: {
    // '^src/(.)*$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
    '^src/*': '../*',
    '^src/(.*)$': '../$1',
  },
  // reporters: ['./reporter'],
};

export default config;
```

And also I have ts.config.json in src folder

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "typeRoots": [ "./types", "./node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

Whatever I do, I tried to update moduleNameMapper with various variants but still facing this error.
But in case I change

```js
import { Service } from 'src/service';
```

to

```js
import { Service } from '../service';
```

it works fine. But developers are against changing paths.
How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

that's not related to nestjs

it's due to using absolute paths in jest, which doesn't supports that by default. See: [Import Absolute Paths in Typescript Jest Tests](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/lmnsdtce3y-import-absolute-paths-in-typescript-jest-tests)

Comment: I tried various variants of paths but still no success with absolute paths

Comment: I'd suggest you to don't use that kind of absolute paths then. For path alias, I've been using `moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptionsPaths)` from `ts-jest`